# Real time comunication between servers and clients

Tags: multithreading, node.js, architecture

I have a socket game server that runs everything on one single process; the problem is when i want to scale out my app. 
Since it is a card game and when there is an event on a table, i can easily reach all the players that are in the same room because i have direct access to their socket connection.

if i want another server (or many depending on the load) it is another complete different process and i need to be able to have for instance 1 room, where players from server 1 can play against players from server 2, and in case server 1 fails, the connections can be taken from server 2 and keep them playing without interruptions.

What would be the architecture for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hosting providers support both websockets and horizontal scaling. This will allow your users to establish a websocket connection with a node. However, you may need an event from that user to broadcast to other users connected to other notes.

You may want to consider something like `RabbitMQ`. By using a `fanout` or `topic` `exchange` you can broadcast the event to a set of listeners. The listeners will be the various nodes in your cluster that are maintaining the websocket connections.

Comment: Thanks Josh, i wonder if there is more documentation about couchqueue, don't know if i can accomplish the same with it since there is not enough documentation online.  But this RabbitMQ is awesome.!!